# How to read, write XLSX files using CSVReader, CSVWriter of OpenCSV? Is it possible?

Tags: apache-poi, xlsx, opencsv

I have the small requirement to update XLSX file data , but i am allowed to use only CSVWriter instead of writing new method to read and write XLSX files. Is there a way to do that?

Instead of converting XLSX to CSV, im thinking to tweak my existing code of handling CSV files to update the XLSX files.

Please suggest if anyone has done it already.

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: What do you want? A CSV? Or an XLSX? They're completely different file formats with completely different libraries to read/write them...

Comment: Yes i agree @Gagravarr . im just curious to know is there a way to tweak the library or something to enable OpenCSV to read or write the xlsx.

Comment: Nope. You'll need to use something like Apache POI for your `xlsx` files, and a different read/export code path

Comment: Anyone has the java code to read csv file and write it in xlsx file